# How to see how scripts are being loaded in a page?

Tags: javascript

Using the Inspector tool in a browser, a waterfall can be seen. Also the type of cause for loading specific elements is mentioned, and it can be explored further in the Stack tab for that specific element.

Is there a way to see a dependency tree showing, how all scripts (or all elements) are subsequently called, one by another?

Answer (score 2):

When you're in the network tab of Chrome's developer tools, you can view the waterfall of all calls that your browser is making to the website's server. If you're trying to see which javascript files are causing certain files to load, I believe that is viewable in the initiator tab. Take a look at the photo below. It shows base.js being the initiating file for when log_event is called.

[image]

If you hover over the initiator it will provide you with more details about it.

Comment: thanks, I know I can do that. I use Firefox Dev and the Initiator column is here called Cause. I too can see the details for each request, separately, when highlighting it, but what I want is to see is a dependency tree.